# few questions about running image hosting website

Tags: web-hosting, security, legal, image-hosting, storage

I'm about to launch a new image hosting website, nevertheless, few questions are still on my mind and i would love to know your take on them.

Q1- how do i prevent users from uploading pornographic materials or illegal materials while still have anonymous uploading (without registration, of course will log ips)

i was thinking about Amazon Rekognition but it's very price

Q2- what would happen if someone uploaded an illegal martial, would i be legally responsible for that or even for not manually monitoring their materials? i'm really lost

Q3- would it be better to serve the images from the website or should i give out direct links for users, on one hand, everything will pass through the server and load the server (would that count as a page visit if i'm returning the image rather than a page) but on the other, it will lighten the load from the server but i won't have control over it (i.e. someone could use my service to start their own and i won't be able to ban their domain/ip)

i'm good for the programming part, but lost in those logistics, any input is highly appreciated

Edit: i've been researching for some time, everyone is advising against open upload, but realistically, it doesn't matter as people will give fake information if they come with bad intentions, also, most of the popular and successful websites, don't require registration, as an end user, why should i share my information with website to share some picture with someone

Comment: Please limit your post to a single question and use that question in the title.  You can edit this to remove extra questions and we will re-open it.

Comment: so i need to post 3 different questions related to the same topic/subject? nah i won't, you need to change your community guidelines..

Comment: Questions here are expected to create a repository of easy answers for the next person with the same problem.  To make that work, the title needs to ask a simplified version of the question.  The answer can't be buried among other answers